# How to generate XML test result report When run spark job with Junit?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, junit

I have spark job written in scala with junit. When  I run this spark job using spark-submit. It is perfectly fine and it gives test results like pass or fail..My requirement is I want this result as XML file...

```
@Test def checkAllAvroFileFormat =
 { 
         org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("avro", avroFileFormat)
 }
```